# AzureDevOps Pipleline force Task to install a certain version / old version of .Net Maui

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, maui

After the latest .Net Maui update, my iOS app will longer build using the macos-12 image. Does anyone know how to specify an older version of .Net Maui using the CmdLine@2 Task? Here is what my current Task looks like.

```
- task: CmdLine@2
  displayName: 'Install Maui'
  inputs:
    script: 'dotnet workload install maui'
```

The new version of .Net Maui seems to be looking for Xcode 14.1 and the iOS 16.1 SDK because it's using microsoft.net.sdk.ios version 16.1.1481.

I'm trying to figure out what version to use and this is getting ridiculous. You would think that I could specify one of these versions, but that's simply not the case. This is so frustrating and makes no sense!!!

https://github.com/dotnet/maui/releases

You would think that something like this would work.

```
- task: CmdLine@2
  displayName: 'Install Maui'
  inputs:
    script: 'dotnet workload install --sdk-version 7.0.1xx maui'
```

https://maui.blob.core.windows.net/metadata/rollbacks/7.0.1xx.json

This seems to suggest that the version of Asp.net determines the .Net Maui version.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/947953/how-do-i-get-net-maui-service-releases.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I was able to install an old version of .Net Maui.

I told the Pipeline to use Version 7.0.100 of Asp.net.

```
- task: UseDotNet@2
  displayName: .NET Version
  inputs:
    packageType: 'sdk'
    version: '7.0.100'
```

I told the Pipeline to use the 7.0.1xx Release version of .Net Maui.

https://github.com/dotnet/maui/tree/release/7.0.1xx

```
- task: CmdLine@2
  displayName: 'Install Maui'
  inputs:
    script: 'dotnet workload install maui --from-rollback-file https://maui.blob.core.windows.net/metadata/rollbacks/7.0.1xx.json --source https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/dnceng/public/_packaging/dotnet7/nuget/v3/index.json --source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json'
```

Answer (score 0):

Maui version will be determined by .net version.

> AzureDevOps Pipleline force Task to install a certain version / old version of .Net Maui

To install a certain version of .net Maui in Azure Pipeline, you can use the [Use dotnet v2 task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/use-dotnet-v2?view=azure-pipelines) to set the .net version of the pipeline.  Then it will install a certain version of Maui.

Here is an example:

```
steps:
- task: UseDotNet@2
  displayName: 'Use .NET Core sdk 7.0.100'
  inputs:
    version: 7.0.100

- script: 'dotnet workload install maui'
  displayName: 'Command Line Script'
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work for me. Have you tested it?

Comment: Yes. I have tested the method and it can work.

Comment: Interesting! If I don't specify the rollback option, it won't install a previous version of .Net Maui.